# Database created by SQLite does not inherit default ACL set for parent directory

Tags: sqlite, acl

I am trying to setup an environment where I have a folder shared between members of a group without touching the `umask` for these users. The permissions for this folder have been set using Access Control List (ACL). Running the `getfacl` gives me:

```
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: my_user
# group: my_group
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:my_group:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:my_group:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

In other words, every time a `my_user` user that belongs to the `my_group` group creates a file inside that folder, that file will have `rw-` for group members. That works with almost every file I create. Everything fine up to now:

```
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 my_user my_group 4.0K Oct 30 10:09 .
drwxrwsr-x+ 7 my_user my_group 4.0K Oct 30 10:04 ..
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_dir_1
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_file_1
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_file_2
```

Now, when I create a database using SQLite, the permissions are different!

```
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 my_user my_group 4.0K Oct 30 10:17 .
drwxrwsr-x+ 7 my_user my_group 4.0K Oct 30 10:04 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 my_user my_group 8.0K Oct 30 10:17 my_database.db   <<<<<
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_dir_1
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_file_1
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 my_user my_group    0 Oct 30 10:09 my_file_2
```

See that the permissions for the `my_database.db` file are `-rw-r--r--+`. How can I make it inherit the ACL permissions so it is created with `-rw-rw-r--+` like the other files?